# Three.js rendering ignores browser zoom

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, 3d, three.js

Three.js rendering appears to ignore browser zoom. An example is http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_text.

This is a problem for several reasons: a) it creates a serious layout issue if one wants to align a three.js rendering with a non-three.js element on a web page that does respond to browser zoom, and b) it blocks the ability to apply responsive design to any web page containing a three.js rendering.

Is there a solution to the problem?

Is there another framework with 3D text capability that handles browser zoom correctly?

Comment: what do you mean by `browser zoom`?

Comment: Zoom percent in web browser. View example from the link provided above or any three.js example and change your web browser's zoom value. You will see that the rendering doesn't change.

Comment: that is not a three.js issue but an application implementation.

Comment: Are you referring to web browser coding or javascript coding for the web page? If the latter is the case, how should the coding be implemented to solve the issue?

Comment: in your resize function (triggered by window resize event) you change the size of the font.

Comment: Thank you. I commented out the body of that function and the problem went away.